# Handling optional field in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Following is my React Component code snippet where one of the fields is optional. Being optional, I have to initialize it `undefined` but this makes it tough to later use it even after type check. I am not sure how to tackle this. I am using typescript version 3.2.2.

```
interface State {
  open: boolean;
  selected?: SelectedFieldType;
}

class CFilter extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    open: false,
    selected: undefined
  };

  onOperatorValueChange = (value: any) => {
    if (typeof this.state.selected !== undefined) {
      console.log(this.state.selected.value); // ERROR: Object is possibly undefined (property): selected undefined
      this.setState({
        selected: {
          ...this.state.selected, // ERROR: Spread types may only be created from object types
          value: value
        }
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (<span>some jsx</span>);
  }
}
```

If I don't intialize `selected`, it will throw me an error

> Property selected doesn't exist

Comment: Try null? undefined for default state and null if you couldn't assign it even after you've tried it?

Comment: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SelectedFieldType | undefined'.:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have react set up so I can't test this, but my *guess* is that you should annotate the type of `state` to `State` when you initialize it, like

```
  // note the annotation
  state: State = {
    open: false,
    selected: undefined
  };
```

instead of letting the compiler infer the type.  It's quite possible that the compiler thinks that `CFilter['state']` is narrower than `State` (`CFilter extends React.Component<Props, State>` means `state` can be any type that *extends* `State`.) and that `CFilter['state']['selected']` is *always* `undefined`.  If so, then `this.state.selected` will always be considered `undefined` and it's impossible to change that with a null-check (it is unfortunate that the error message complains about it being "possibly" undefined when it thinks it is *necessarily* undefined, but that's how it is.)

Try the explicit annotation and see if it fixes the problem.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: One more thing - `typeof this.state.selected` is a string, so it should be checked against the string literal in quotes `'undefined'`, not actual `undefined`:   `typeof this.state.selected !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

*Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SelectedFieldType | undefined'* sounds odd... maybe you could try to add just for testing a pipe allowing null value to SelectedFieldType. But it is bizarre to have to do it.

```
interface State {
  open: boolean;
  selected?: SelectedFieldType | null;
}
```

The observation from @jcalz also seems very good. You should try it.

If it don't work, you could try to re-write your code to something like:

```
class CFilter extends React.Component {
  state: State = {
    open: false,
    selected: null,
  };

  onOperatorValueChange = (value: any) => {
    if (this.state.selected) {
      this.setState({
        selected: { 
          ...this.state.selected,
          value
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

I have tested [on this stackblitz](https://react-ts-hmfw4s.stackblitz.io) and it seems to work fine with no errors.